# tf.random.set_seed() TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

`tf.random.set_seed(7)`in TF Version: `2.6.0` produces `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`

This one `tf.compat.v1.set_random_seed(7)` worked for me in `TF 2.6.0` in Google Colab but dont know why I cant do it with `tf.random.set_seed(7)`

Comment: Did you try feeding it `lambda:7`?

Comment: @Bey Could you show an example please?

Comment: it looks like set_seed expects a function, so why not wrap it in a function that returns 7?

Comment: I tried that too @Bey.

Comment: I should not give that error. Could you please give reproducible code? I run the code in `tf 2.6` on colab, no issue was found.

Comment: @M.Innat, Now the same code is working fine. Cant understand why it was not working earlier.

Comment: I just ran it in 2.6 with no problem. But in any case, you should migrate to the tf.random.Generator API. tf.random.uniform and tf.random.normal are not very random. It's really hard to debug when your source of randomness is not random. https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/random_numbers
>Warning: The old RNGs from TF 1.x such as tf.random.uniform and tf.random.normal are not yet deprecated but strongly discouraged.

Comment: On Colab with Tensorflow 2.6, `tf.random.set_seed(7)` and `tf.compat.v1.set_random_seed(7)` works just fine. It is recommended to use `tf.random.set_seed(7)` for TF v2.6. `tf.compat.v1.set_random_seed`, API was designed for TensorFlow v1. Thanks!

Comment: If you use set_seed(using assign) for eg., tf.random.set_seed = 42  and then try to use tf.random.set_seed(123) (callable) in the same colab notebook, this error occurs. Make sure you do not assign values to set_seed before using tf.random.set_seed() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TF 2.6

If you use set_seed(using assign) for eg., tf.random.set_seed = 42 and then try to use tf.random.set_seed(123) (callable) in the same colab notebook, this error occurs. See scenarios below.

Setting seed using assign

```
tf.random.set_seed = 123
print(tf.random.uniform([1]))  # generates 'A1'
print(tf.random.uniform([1]))  # generates 'A2'
```

Output:

```
tf.Tensor([0.48962688], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.42140496], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
```

Now in the next cell, if you try to call the function like below, the error occurs.

```
tf.random.set_seed(123)
print(tf.random.uniform([1]))  # generates 'A1'
print(tf.random.uniform([1]))  # generates 'A2'
```

Output:

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
        <ipython-input-25-6ad9ca1b84ce> in <module>()
    ----> 1 tf.random.set_seed(123)
          2 print(tf.random.uniform([1]))  # generates 'A1'
          3 print(tf.random.uniform([1]))  # generates 'A2'
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Now, If you restart the notebook and run only the tf.random.set_seed(123) function, it works good.

```
tf.random.set_seed(123)
print(tf.random.uniform([1]))  # generates 'A1'
print(tf.random.uniform([1]))  # generates 'A2'
```

Output:

```
tf.Tensor([0.12615311], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.88968754], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
```

The solution is to make sure you do not assign values to set_seed before using tf.random.set_seed() function.